# Looping the same set of functions in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="container">

    <a class="button" href="#">John Doe</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Jane Doe</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Will Smith</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Bill Smith</a>
    <a class="button" href="#">Tony Danza</a>

</div>
<div class="another-div"></div>
```

I want to split those `a.button` up into groups of 4 and wrap them in a `div` with jQuery, which I do like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.container a.button').slice( 0, 4 ).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
  $('div.wrapper').each(function(){
      $(this).appendTo('.another-div');
  });

  /* Just repeating that again below... */

  $('.container a.button').slice( 0, 4 ).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
  $('div.wrapper').each(function(){
      $(this).appendTo('.another-div');
  });

  /* ...and so on. */

 });
</script>
```

Note that after I use `.slice()` and `.wrapAll()` I move those down into `div.wrapper`, so eventually there is nothing left in the original `.container` div.

There may be 10s or 100s of `a.button` though. Is there a way to repeat this action without just pasting the same code in over and over again? Is there some type of loop I could do that would check if there are any more instances of `$('.container a.button')`?

Answer (score 0):

Update your script function as below , hope this helps

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".container a.button").each(function(){
  $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
 });
 
 var allchildren = $(".container").children();
 $(".another-div").append(allchildren);
 });
 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't wrap them into groups of 4.